# Перевод числа в массив байтов

Tags: java, byte

Как представить число (`int`, `float`) в виде массива байтов в Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)-ом:

```
int value = 100000;
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();
```

и

```
float floatValue = 100.5f;
byte[] floatBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(floatValue).array();
```

Answer (score -2):

Возможно более простым решением будет:

```
String string = String.valueOf(1000); //any type: int, double, float...
byte[] bytes = string .getBytes();
```

Comment: Но это же байты ASCII символов, а не то, что требовалось)

Comment: Вопрос звучал так: "Как представить число (int, float) в виде массива байтов в Java?" С помощью метода getBytes(), вызванного на объекте класса String, мы получаем массив байтов. Чем обосновано ваше критическое замечание "Не то, что требовалось?"

Comment: Я просто полагаю, что между `0x31303030` и `0x000003e8` есть небольшая разница.